# C# Cookie value stored as name=value

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, webforms

This is what happens after a while, after my solution in [Remembering Session in iframe with ASP.NET WebForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62638886/remembering-session-in-iframe-with-asp-net-webforms)

It was working fine, but I don't know how this happens now:

```
        int utcOffset = 120; // added for example sake
        HttpCookie UTCOffset = new HttpCookie("UTCOffset");
        UTCOffset.Values.Add("utcOffset", utcOffset.ToString());
        UTCOffset.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(UTCOffset);
```

Instead of cookie value "120", I get value "utcOffset=120" ???

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is working as you are telling it to in code. If you want it to be as you say in the question, it would be

```
    int utcOffset = 120; // added for example sake
    HttpCookie UTCOffset = new HttpCookie("UTCOffset");
    UTCOffset.Value = utcOffset.ToString();
    UTCOffset.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(UTCOffset);
```